# C# return full path with GetFiles

Tags: c#, getfiles

Use this code for search files in directory:

```
FileInfo[] files = null;
string path = some_path;
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
files = folder.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This return only filename and extension (text.exe). How to return full path to file(C:\bla\bla\bla\text.exe)?

If I use `Directory.GetFiles("*.*")`, this return full path. But if folder contains point in name(C:\bla\bla\test.0.1), result contains path to folder without file:

- 0 C:\bla\bla\bla\text.exe
- 1 C:\bla\bla\test.0.1
- 2 C:\bla\text.exe

etc.

Comment: *contains point in name* - do you mean a dot `.`?

Comment: yep, for example: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_1394.inf.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_beafdf583b909e3f

Comment: no, not for example. please explain what you mean *exactly*

Comment: @Aschratt [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) **does** return `FileInfo[]`!

Comment: @Default: Yes, sorry... I mixed it up with `Directory.GetFiles()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)

Comment: @Aschratt well, you still got the reputation for it, so it's still a small win for you I guess :) I guess I should blame the approvers for not proofreading...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`FileInfo` contains a `FullName` property, which you can use to retrieve full path to a file

```
var fullNames = files.Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
```

### Check

This code on my machine:

```
FileInfo[] files = null;
string path = @"C:\temp";
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
files = folder.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//you need string from FileInfo to denote full path
IEnumerable<string> fullNames = files.Select(file => file.FullName);

Console.WriteLine ( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fullNames ) );
```

prints

```
C:\temp\1.dot 
C:\temp\1.jpg 
C:\temp\1.png 
C:\temp\1.txt 
C:\temp\2.png 
C:\temp\a.xml 
...
```

### Full solution

The solution to your problem might look like this:

```
string path = @"C:\temp";
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var directories = folder.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


IEnumerable<string> directoriesWithDot = 
 directories.Where(dir => dir.Name.Contains("."))
            .Select(dir => dir.FullName);


IEnumerable<string> filesInDirectoriesWithoutDot = 
 directories.Where(dir => !dir.Name.Contains("."))
            .SelectMany(dir => dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            .Select(file => file.FullName);


Console.WriteLine ( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, directoriesWithDot.Union(filesInDirectoriesWithoutDot) ) );
```

Comment: @LukeHennerley `GetFiles` returns a `FileInfo[]` or am I missing something? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx

Comment: @LukeHennerley the `files` variable is a `FileInfo[]`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov If you use a Select projection, you're returning a IEnumerable<string> instead of the original FileInfo array.

Comment: @LukeHennerley this is a **static** method on `DirectoryInfo`

Comment: @ken2k he needs strings, as he noted at `How to return full path to file(C:\bla\bla\bla\text.exe)?`

Comment: @LukeHennerley: you're wrong, he' using `DirectoryInfo`, not `Directory` and `GetFiles` for `DirectoryInfo` returns `FileInfo[]`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi ah yeah, my bad. Didn't clock on to that bit.

Answer (score 7):

Each [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object has a `FullName` property.

---

> But if folder contains point in name (C:\bla\bla\test.0.1), result contains path to folder without file

This is an entirely different issue with possibly diffeent answers/workarounds. Can you be more specific?
I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FileInfo`.

```
Directory.GetFiles("", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(file => new FileInfo(file).FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllFilesRecursively(string inputFolder)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<string>();
        queue.Enqueue(inputFolder);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            inputFolder = queue.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(inputFolder))
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("GetAllFilesRecursively: " + ex);
            }
            string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(inputFolder);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("GetAllFilesRecursively: " + ex);
            }
            if (files != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    yield return files[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
void GetFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo d= new DirectoryInfo(strFolderPath);
       //file extension for pdf
        var files = d.GetFiles("*.pdf*");
        FileInfo[] subfileInfo = files.ToArray<FileInfo>();

        if (subfileInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subfileInfo.Length; j++)
            {
                bool isHidden = ((File.GetAttributes(subfileInfo[j].FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden);
                if (!isHidden)
                {
                    string strExtention = th.GetExtension(subfileInfo[j].FullName);
                    if (strExtention.Contains("pdf"))
                    {                            
                        string path = subfileInfo[j].FullName;
                        string name = bfileInfo[j].Name;                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FileSystemInfo.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) property.

> Gets the full path of the directory or file.