# How can I add an image into a list in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to index multiple folders of images into multiple lists. Currently, I'm trying to use `System.IO`'s `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` to do this, but my lists' types are `Texture2D` and so it cannot convert them. So how can I add these images to the lists?

Relevant code:

```
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.IO;

    public List<Texture2D> daytimeImages = new List<Texture2D>();

    private void Start() {
        DirectoryInfo daytimeDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(daytimePath);
        FileInfo[] daytimePictures = nighttimeDirectory.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in nighttimePictures)
        {
            daytimeImages.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keyur's answer should do it but please add some kind of protection to the code so that only image files(jpg,png...) are loaded. The code in your question will just get every file in that folder. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634328/3785314) answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of the answers [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/432655/loading-texture-file-from-pngjpg-file-on-disk.html)

This function may help you, it converts image from file path to Texture2d using the [LoadImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) function:

```
public static Texture2D LoadImage(string filePath) 
{
    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))     //you can skip this since you are only passing files that exist
    {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData);
    }
    return tex;
}
```

You can use it as follows (EDITED to add [.FullName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477535/6741868))

```
foreach (FileInfo file in nighttimePictures)
{
    daytimeImages.Add(LoadImage(file.FullName));  //edited
}
```

Comment: Trying that gives me an error that it cannot convert FileInfo to a string in the foreach loop.

Comment: Check out my edit, I forgot to extract the file path from the FileInfo.